# Finding Center of Mass

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, centroid

Can someone explain what I did wrong? I want to correct my mistakes on this midterm. I suspect my equation for the moment about the y-axis is wrong.

[image]

Comment: Its in your graph you made a mistake, where you put a vertical segment. It should be the other one. Remember that one side of the rectangle must be part of the x-axis. Look at yours? One side lies in the y-axis?

Comment: @ΘΣΦ GenSan I thought it didn't matter? My textbook shows both ways (horizontal and vertical).

Comment: That's not the issue. The triangular plate you choose  is wrong.

Comment: @ΘΣΦ GenSan Ignoring the vertical line, is it then the correct graph.

Comment: $\bar{x}=\dfrac{\int_0^1 3x(2x)dx+\int_1^3 3x(3-x)dx}{\int_0^1 3(2x)dx+\int_1^3 3(3-x)dx}$

Comment: In fact, the one that you present for $\overline{x}$ and $\overline{y}$ is wrong. See the above comment of @MyGlasses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much better if I show the graph of the triangular region: It is given in the shaded area below:

[image]
 I do suggest you to reformulate the formulas for $\overline{x}$ and $\overline{y}$ by considering the horizontal segment approach. Its easier than the vertical segment approach.

I will go out for now. In case you want the details of the one I suggested, just ask me and I fix my answer when I come back.

Comment: Dear god...I'm so stupid. Thank you, I understand now.